# How to collect results after filtering and mapping a parallelStream in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to extract a collection of objects from another collection. The objects to be filtered must be a specific type (or subtype) and must intersect with a given `Shape`. I want to do it with `parallelStream`

I have the following code:

```
public class ObjectDetector {
...
    public ObjectDetector(final Collection<WorldObject> objects,
        final BiFunction<Shape, Shape, Boolean> isIntersecting) {
    ...
    }

    public List<ISensor> getSonarObjects(final Shape triangle) {
        return selectIntersecting(triangle, ISensor.class);
    }

    private <T> List<T> selectIntersecting(Shape triangle, Class<T> type) {
        return objects.parallelStream()
                .filter(o -> type.isInstance(o) && isIntersecting.apply(o.getShape(), triangle))
                .map(o -> type.cast(o)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problematic part is in the `List<T> selectIntersecting(Shape triangle, Class<T> type)` method, in which `objects` is a `Collection` and `isIntersecting` is a `BiFunction<Shape,Shape,Boolean>`.

When I'm using `stream()` instead of `parallelStream()` all my tests are green. So I may assume that the filtering and mapping logic works fine. However when I am trying to use the `parallelStream()` my tests are failing unpredictably. The only coherence that I was able to observe is that the `size()` of the returned `List<T>` is less than or equal to (but of course never greater) the size I expect.

A failing testcase for example:

```
int counter = 0;
public BiFunction<Shape, Shape, Boolean> every2 = (a, b) -> {
    counter++;
    return counter % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
};

@Test
public void getEvery2Sonar() {
    assertEquals("base list size must be 8",8,list.size());
    ObjectDetector detector = new ObjectDetector(list, every2);
    List<ISensor> sonarable = detector.getSonarObjects(triangle);
    assertEquals("number of sonar detectables should be 3", 3, sonarable.size());
}
```

And the test result is:

> Failed tests:   getEvery2Sonar(hu.oe.nik.szfmv.environment.ObjectDetectorTest): number of sonar detectables should be 3 expected:<3> but was:<2>

In my understanding - as it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44083587/6635282) - it is possible to collect a `parallelStream` into non-concurrent `Collection`.

I've also tried to find some clues on the Parallelism tutorial [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html), but I'm still clueless.

Could someone please provide me an explanation about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predicate function has side effects - this is going to go badly with `parallelStream` because the evaluation order across the input stream is non-deterministic, plus you have no locking on your mutable state.

Indeed, the documentation for [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) states<sup>*</sup> that the predicate must be [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).

I'm not sure what behaviour you're trying to achieve here, so I'm not sure what an appropriate "fix" might be.

---

<sub>* No pun intended.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Oliver Charlesworth!
You are right. In fact, I totally lost sight of that this specific predicate causes a side effect by incrementing a counter. That test case is wrong.
I was intended to test the Shape intersection inspection logic (it has no side effect) and the stream processing separately. So I was trying to write as simple predicates as possible i.e. true for all, true for none, true for every second...