# Convert an arraylist of integer to arraylist of boolean

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist containing integers want to convert this into arraylist of boolean.

The code which I tried is containing a loop is there any other faster way to do the same.

The sample used.

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> changeThis(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    ArrayList<Boolean> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
        a.add(arr.get(i) == 1);
    }
    return a;
}
```

and the input for the above method is as follows:

```
changeThis(arr);//arr has [1,0,1,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Have you tried to cast?It might sounds funny but this may hack it.

Comment: @Ullas Hunka are you looking for faster way in terms of performance or in terms of amount of code?

Comment: Try thread safe parallel streaming for increase performance if you have a massive list of object to iterate over. here is a link on how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44083598/4762762

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: given the update that the actual is `value[index] == 1`, the answer is of course:

```
return incomingList.stream().map( (number) -> number == 1 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This could then be changed to use `parallelStream()` to get to results *quicker*. The parallel solution is of course only decreasing overall runtime when talking about a really *large* number of numbers in that list! For small data sets, using `stream()` or `parallelStream()` will most likely *increase* the time required to compute the result list.

The other thing to look at: where are the numbers coming actually from?  Maybe there is a chance to use an `IntStream` instead of `List<Integer>`.

---

For completeness, the initial answer, based on the assumption that we need to compare against the *index*, instead of `1`:

Actually, this is one of the occasions where there is *no* way to improve much (except the wording, as the variable names are really meaningless).

The thing is: in order to compute the condition, you need to compare the list slot against its *index*.

Thus you need that *counting* for loop (somehow). Any `stream()` based solution would require extra work to get to that information; same when using `foreach()`.

So, long story short: stay with the "old school" iterative way here!

Comment: Sorry, I dont get that comment?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **stream**:

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> changeThis(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
        return arr.stream().map(e -> (e == 1) ).collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ) );
}
```